# CSS iPhone not rendering corectly

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, media-queries

I know this may be a usual topic, but I really need your assistance. I've made a website which you can find at http://safeway-itnovation.com/ but it does not render properly on iPhone devices on the landscape mode.

Here is a video showing how it should look on iPhone devices (portrait and landscape):
https://vimeo.com/580283262

Here is a video showing how it actually looks on my iPhone 7 Plus (landscape): https://vimeo.com/580284241

As you can see, the second section (with the white background) is completely off. Here is the GitHub repository for everyone who wants to see the full code: https://github.com/MarcVana/SafeWay-website.

But, let me elaborate shortly. My queries look like this:
[queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mwah.png) and they are optimized for all sorts of websites with Autoprefixer on VS Code (for the last 10 versions of browsers).

I've put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` at the start of my HTML file.

The 4 boxes in the white section have `position: absolute`.

There is another problem in the videos, my pictures are not rendering correctly even if I've resized them at 1080p and also used Photoshop to export them for a website, none of them being larger than 1MB. But that's another question and should not be answered here.

If you need any more info, feel free to ask me anything:D.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. The question as such does not meet the SO guidelines as it is missing details and clarity aswell as debugging details. Note, that you may not just link to your website as it holds no value for SO. Creating a minimal reproduciable code snippet is also the first step of debugging yourself.

Comment: I´m sad to say, but on PC, it also not renders correctly. But it is another problem. From width 1226 and bigger is p with class motto on the p with class under-motto. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Lrp.jpg)

Comment: (In smaller screen there is also problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kG1b.png)

Comment: Those are other problems which I was not quite aware of, but I was asking about the difference between the Inspect tab and the actual website:D. It shows good when I use developer tools and resize it to iPhone 6/7/8 Plus, but when I actually open the website on an iPhone 7 Plus it does not render as in the dev tools.

Comment: I know, sorry :)

Comment: @tacoshy what should I add?

Comment: @MetropolisCZ don't apologize, thanks for the response anyway and I will solve them as soon as I can:D

Comment: I thiks he wants [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not whole website link